# get value from approve slack to php

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

Here, I tried to make attaching interactive message buttons from web app to slack, I was already post message to slack with JSON. Now how I get value of button approve when approve in slack to php/web app?

**Function**

```
function slacktest($message, $room = "channel-name")
{
    $room = ($room) ? $room : "channel-name";
    $data = "payload=" . json_encode(array(
            "channel"       =>  "#{$room}",
            "text"          =>  $message,
            "username"      =>  "Beny",
            "attachments"   =>  array([
                                'fallback' => 'Hey! See this message',
                                'pretext'  => 'New Approval Request ! ',
                                'color'    => '#ff6600',
                                'actions'  => array
                      (
                      [
                      'name'     => "one",
                      'text'     => "Approve",
                      'value'    => '1',
                      'url'      => 'insertapprove.php',
                      'type'     => 'button',    
                      'confirm'  => [                                                                       
                'title' => 'Confirm',
                'text'  => 'Your Leave Requested has been Approved',
                'ok_text' => 'Yes',
                'dismiss_text' => 'No',
                                    ]
                                    ],
                                  [
                'name'     => "two",
                'text'     => "Reject",
                'value'    => '2',
                'type'     => 'button',
                'confirm'  => [
                'title'        => 'Confirm',
                'text'         => 'Your Leave Requested is Cancelled',
                'ok_text'      => 'No',
                'dismiss_text' => 'No',
                               ]
                               ]
                               )
                               ]),   
      "icon_url"      =>  'http://localhost/images/nestor-icon.png'
        ));
    $ch = curl_init("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result     = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Slack response : ". $result ;
    return $result;
}
```

**call function**

```
$message2 = "Tes Channel 2";
$channel2 = "random";
slacktest($message2,$channel2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "value back" after someone clicked the button, Slack will send a request to your app. For that Slack needs to know the URL of your app and your app needs to be able to handle interactive message requests from Slack.

Therefore you need to define a Slack app. There you can specify the URL of your app (called "Request URL", under Interactive Components) that Slack will call once a button is pressed.

For more details see **Responding to message** actions in the [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons).

Comment: yes, click on "Create New App" at that link to create your Slack App

Comment: so can i get value back to my localhost app ?  i'm confuse to make new slack app.

Comment: You can, buy only if you expose your local Webserver to Internet. To do that safely I can recommend ngrok.com. I use that every day for my dev work on slack apps

Comment: what "value back" is ?  is the value '1' from button?

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked. Its all explained there. If you then have additional issue feel free to open a new question.

Comment: i'm confuse how to get the value, what should i do ?.  create slack app first or write it in code php(my web app) to connect it.

Comment: this first i tried, and when approve it say "Darn – that didn't work. Only Slack Apps can add interactive elements to messages." ,
and then i create new slack app,  i tried again, and when approve it say "Hmm, that didn't work, because this app is missing a request URL. Define one here: Beny".

Comment: you are getting there. As mentioned in my answer you need to specify the request URL under Interactive Components. If you app runs on your local machine, you will need to first install ngrok and then give Slack a ngrok URL. That looks like `https://abc12345.ngrok.io/dev/myapp.php`

Comment: https://5eb9c50f.ngrok.io/ this my ngrok URL.. and https://abc12345.ngrok.io/dev/myapp.php(dev/myapp.php) is u're aplication folder ?

Comment: i already make ngrok url to my php file and it works, now how to know it's approved or not ? should i make script php to get the action ?